# What are items that help us to get vision spells?

Tags: league-of-legends

I wonder if there is an item that expose chosen map area when castesd?

For now I just know the trinket item [`Farsight Alteration`](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Farsight_Alteration) in [this LoL category](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Ward_items) and love to use it. Need one more item to get more vision.

If you know some, please share.

Answer (score 3):

The only ways to gain vision **with items** on summoners rift are [Ward items](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Ward_items) and [Icy ghosts active on FQC](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_Queen's_Claim).
Some champion spells have effect similar to Farsight i.e. Ashe's Hawkshot.
There also *was* a summoner spell "Clairvoyance" that provided vision like Farsight, but now it's removed from game.

Comment: Note that this is only true for Summoner's RIft. Howling Abyss and Twisted Treeline have items that grant something similar to an ashe arrow (E) explosion (but point and click without the travel)